# Android Nougat Webview screen width

Tags: android, android-webview, android-7.1-nougat

Hello I am having an issue with the Webview element in Android Nougat.

I want the content to not be bigger than the screensize and it works perfectely in older Android versions but not in the latest one.

If have this in my code:

```
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

This is what it looks like in older versions:
[Older version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLmFp.png)

And this is how it looks like in Android Nougat:
[Latest version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMzH1.png)

Is there anything I could do to make it only use the actual screensize?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best solution for this problem but after more research and testing I found a little fix for my issue.

I added `.setInitialScale(getScale());`

```
private int getScale(){
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    Double val = new Double(width)/new Double(width);
    val = val * 100d;
    return val.intValue();
}
```

And here is how it looks like with this fix: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t43Yb.png)